# Manual implementation bayern to RGB

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement image transformation Bayern Pattern -> RGB

I uploaded this image: [image: mosaic picture]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import os
PATH = 'data/'

file_path = os.path.join(PATH, 'oldwell_mosaic.png')
img = cv2.imread(file_path, 0)
w, h = img.shape
new_image = np.zeros((w, h, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
# Green
new_image[1::2,1::2,1] = img[1::2,1::2]
new_image[::2, ::2, 1] = img[::2, ::2]

# Blue
new_image[1::2,::2,0] = img[1::2,::2]

# Red
new_image[::2, 1::2, 2] = img[::2, 1::2]
```

In the above example I use this pattern:
[image]

I am supposed to interpolate the missing values but the places with 'no values' are actually filled with zeros. When I perform this:

```
kernel = np.ones((4,4), np.float)/16
new_image[:,:,2] = cv2.filter2D(new_image[:, :, 2], -1, kernel)
```

I don't get the expected result as I'm using zeros in interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using **python** nor **opencv** but was curious so here low level **C++** approach for this:

1. **process image by bands separately**
2. **for each pixel you need intensity accumulator `acc[][]` and counter `cnt[][]`**

   the need for counter can be avoided. You can use predefined counts encoded in similar manner then the `mask` in my code but this mean handling special cases on edges and corners of image. I chose `acc,cnt` for  simplicity (they fit into 32bit easily so there is no point to not using it).

   The division can be done with bit-shift for speed (except on edges and corners)
3. **clear `acc,cnt` with zero**
4. **process each pixel containing processed band**

   add the band intensity to `acc` and increment `cnt` to pixel position and also to all neighbors not containing this band.
5. **after whole image processed compute pixel band value**

   simply by

   ```
   pixel[y][x].band = acc[y][x]/cnt[y][x]
   ```

   By this you can use the same buffer for `acc,cnt` for next band.

My **C++** implementation:

```cpp
    picture pic0,pic1,pic2; // pic0 - original input image,pic1 output, pic2 temp band interpolation
    int x,y,a,b,i,j;
    const int mask[3][6][6]=    // bayern mask for eac band 3 bands and common size of 2x2 and 3x3 is 6x6
        {
        // blue
            {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,1},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,1},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,1},
            },
        // green
            {
            {0,1,0,1,0,1},
            {1,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,1},
            {1,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,1,0,1,0,1},
            {1,0,1,0,1,0},
            },
        // red
            {
            {1,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,0,1,0,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0},
            },
        };
    // prepare buffers
    pic1.resize(pic0.xs  ,pic0.ys  ); pic1.pf=_pf_rgba; pic1.clear(0);
    pic2.resize(pic0.xs+2,pic0.ys+2); pic2.pf=_pf_uu;   // size enlarged to avoid edge conditions statements
    // process bands
    for (b=0;b<3;b++)
        {
        pic2.clear(0);              // clear acc,cnt
        for (j=0,y=0;y<pic0.ys;y++,(j==5)?j=0:j++)
         for (i=0,x=0;x<pic0.xs;x++,(i==5)?i=0:i++)
          if (mask[b][j][i])        // process only band b pixels
            {
            a=pic0.p[y][x].db[0];   // grayscale intensity
            // add to 4 neighbors
            pic2.p[y+0][x+1].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+0][x+1].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+1][x+0].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+1][x+0].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+1][x+1].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+1][x+1].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+1][x+2].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+1][x+2].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+2][x+1].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+2][x+1].dw[1]++;
            if (b==picture::_g) continue;
            // add to 8 neighbors (for r,b bands)
            pic2.p[y+0][x+0].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+0][x+0].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+0][x+2].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+0][x+2].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+2][x+0].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+2][x+0].dw[1]++;
            pic2.p[y+2][x+2].dw[0]+=a; pic2.p[y+2][x+2].dw[1]++;
            }
        for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++) // convert to color band
         for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)
          pic1.p[y][x].db[b]=pic2.p[y+1][x+1].dw[0]/pic2.p[y+1][x+1].dw[1];
        }
```

**I use my own picture class for images so some members are:**

`xs,ys` is size of image in pixels

`p[y][x].dd` is pixel at `(x,y)` position as 32 bit integer type

`clear(color)` clears entire image with `color`

`resize(xs,ys)` resizes image to new resolution

`bmp` is **VCL** encapsulated **GDI** Bitmap with `Canvas` access

`pf` holds actual pixel format of the image:

```
enum _pixel_format_enum
    {
    _pf_none=0, // undefined
    _pf_rgba,   // 32 bit RGBA
    _pf_s,      // 32 bit signed int
    _pf_u,      // 32 bit unsigned int
    _pf_ss,     // 2x16 bit signed int
    _pf_uu,     // 2x16 bit unsigned int
    _pixel_format_enum_end
    };
```

`color` and pixels are encoded like this:

```
union color
    {
    DWORD dd; WORD dw[2]; byte db[4];
    int i; short int ii[2];
    color(){}; color(color& a){ *this=a; }; ~color(){}; color* operator = (const color *a) { dd=a->dd; return this; }; /*color* operator = (const color &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
```

The bands are:

```
enum{
    _x=0,   // dw
    _y=1,

    _b=0,   // db
    _g=1,
    _r=2,
    _a=3,

    _v=0,   // db
    _s=1,
    _h=2,
    };
```

The bayern mask has `1` for pixels that has the color band included and item `mask[band][j=0][i=0]` represents `pixel[y=0][x=0]`. Finally here the result: for your input image:

[image: colors]

Comment: btw it is enough to have the masks `2x2` instead of `6x6`